# How to extract day, month and year from Date using Java?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date date = formatter.parse("2020/05/06");
```

I need to extract day, month and year from it i.e.

```
int day = 06;
int  month = 05;
int year = 2020;
```

but when I use

```
int day = date.getDay();
int month = date.getMonth();
int day = date.getYear();
```

its not working.

Comment: _its not working._ What does that mean? Please provide a [mcve], and see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Probably expecting the day of the month? IIRC in Java and JS it's `getDate`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: [I downvoted because "it's not working" is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: Even if you insisted on using `Date`, you should still stay far away from the deprecated `getXxxx`methods. They have been deprecated since February 1997 because they work unreliably across time zones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Date` as it is deprecated.  Use [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) as follows.

```
LocalDate ld  = LocalDate.parse("2020/05/06", 
              DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd"));
int year = ld.getYear();
int month = ld.getMonthValue();
int day = ld.getDayOfMonth();
System.out.println(month + " " + day + " " + year);
```

Prints

```
5 6 2020
```

Check out the other date/time related classes in the  [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to use the new api as [answered by WJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62643228/1398418) but if for some reason you want to use the old api you should use `Calendar`

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
formatter.parse("2020/11/06");
Calendar calendar = formatter.getCalendar();

int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // add 1 because it returns 0-11
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

System.out.println(day);
System.out.println(month);
System.out.println(year);
```

Comment: Fully correct. And I agree, we prefer to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: Why is It printing YEAR = 1940? I need current Year =2020

Comment: @GurkiratSingh You need to parse the date you want. I added it to the answer.