# How to get date in Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, date, kotlin, dayofmonth

I am a beginner in Android and I need code to get today number (from local date).
Like this way:
A `var` is `Iday`. And today is 8th October so `Iday` should be equal to `8`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract day, month and year from Date using Java? \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62643131/how-to-extract-day-month-and-year-from-date-using-java)

Answer (score 2):

### [`LocalDate#getDayOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfMonth--)

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Today at the default time-zone (your JVM's time-zone)
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

        // Day of month today
        int dayOfMonth = date.getDayOfMonth();

        // Display
        System.out.println("Today, the day of month is " + dayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Today, the day of month is 8
```

If you want to get today's date at some other time zone, use [`LocalDate now(ZoneId zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) as shown below:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Today at Melbourne
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Australia/Melbourne"));

        // Day of month today
        int dayOfMonth = date.getDayOfMonth();

        // Display
        System.out.println("Today, the day of month is " + dayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Today, the day of month is 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Callendar` and `get` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)).

```
import java.util.*

val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
val dayOfMonth =  cal[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH]

println(dayOfMonth) // 8 -> 8th October 2020
```

`getInstance()`:

> Gets a calendar using the default time zone and locale. The Calendar returned is based on the current time in the default time zone with the default locale.

---

Deprecated:

```
import java.util.*

val currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().time
println(currentTime.date) // 8
```

Comment: `Calendar` is deprecated in preference to the `java.time` package.